# Compare elements of two list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comparison

I have been given two lists, say list1 and list2. I have to arrange the elements of the list1 in such a way that at particular index the element of list1 is greater than the element of list2. We have to find how many such elements of list1 are there.
For example:

```
list1=[20,30,50]
list2=[60,40,25]
```

Here only element index 2 is greater i.e. 50>25, but if we swap 50 and 30 in list1 
So,

```
list1=[20,50,30]
list2=[60,40,25]
```

then 50 > 40 ( at index 1) and 30 > 25 (at index 2). So we got 2 elements 50 and 30 which are greater at their respective index.
Here is my approach

```
def swap(a,b):
    a,b=b,a
    return a,b
n=3
g=list(map(int,input().split()))
o=list(map(int,input().split()))
c=0
for i in range(n):
    if o[i]>g[i]:
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if g[j]>o[i]:
                g[i],g[j]=swap(g[i],g[j])
                c+=1
                break
    else:
        c+=1
print(c)
```

But for

```
list1= [3,6,7,5,3,5,6,2,9,1]
list2= [2,7,0,9,3,6,0,6,2,6]
```

Its giving c=6 but expected output is c=7

Comment: the order of the final lists it is important ?

Comment: This is not so much a python question as it is an algorithmic question. Perhaps suggest an algorithm in pseudocode?

Comment: How come 20 and 60 are left in their original index positions when 20 is not greater than 60?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle because there is no element in list1 that is greater than 60

Comment: So whats your expected output? a count of how many elements in list1 are greater then elements in list 2?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes but the elements at their respective indexes.

Comment: you should update your question to show your expected output and also the code you have tried so far

Comment: Do you need to exclude duplicates or somehow restrict the swaps ? Your latest example would give a count of 5 if you exclude duplicates or 9 if you don't because 1>0 and 3>2 each occur twice and 7>6 occurs 3 times.  The pairs should be: `1>0, 1>0, 3>2, 3>2, 5>3, 7>6, 7>6, 7>6, 9>7, count=9`

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort the two lists and then run through them to find "matches" where a value of list1 is greater than the next value of list2.  This will pair up the values with the smallest possible difference and thus maximize the pairings.

For example:

```
list1=[20,30,50]
list2=[60,40,25]

iter1 = iter(sorted(list1))  # iterator to run through sorted list1
n1    = next(iter1,None)     # n1 is current number in list1
count = 0                    # count of paired elements (n1>n2)
for n2 in sorted(list2):               # go through sorted list 2
    while n1 is not None and n1 <= n2: # skip over ineligible items of list1
        n1 = next(iter1,None)
    if n1 is None: break               # stop when list 1 is exhausted
    count += 1                         # count 1 pair and move on to next of list2

print(count) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1= [3,6,7,5,3,5,6,2,9,1]
list2= [2,7,0,9,3,6,0,6,2,6]

list1 = sorted(list1)
it = iter(enumerate(list1))
list2  = sorted(list2)
c = next(it)
good = []
for i, n in enumerate(list2 ):
    try:
        while c[1] < n:
            c = next(it)
        good.append([i, c[0]])
        c = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break

for idx1, idx2 in good:
    list1[idx1], list1[idx2] = list1[idx2], list1[idx1]

final_l1_l2 = sum(a > b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))# how many l1 are > l2
print(final_l1_l2)
```

output:

```
   7
```

also, you can print list1 and list2 after the rearrange:

```
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9, 5]
[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9]
```

the idea is to sort both lists and then to check what elements from `list1` are greater than the elements from `list2` if one element from `list1` it is smaller then the current element from `list2` just go to the next element from the `list1` till there are no more elements in `list1`